# Rails custom select name screwing up strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a form for a "group", and on it is a select box like so:

```
    <%= f.text_field :description %> 
    <%= select_tag 'custom_people', People.all  %>
```

in my group controller:

```
def group_params

    params.require(:group).permit(:description, :custom_people)
```

and when the form submits, I can see custom_people in my params:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"",
>   "group"=>{"description"=>"something"}, "custom_people"=>"1", 
>   "commit"=>"Save"}

but in my controller action group_params only gets

> {"description"=>"something"}

Is this because the select_tag has a custom name, and I need a different syntax in my strong params? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure those are the actual params that appeared in the log? I believe those are not. Please check again.

Comment: You want to use `f.select :custom_people, People.all`. See [*FormBuilder#select*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select)

Comment: @Pavan yes, those are the actual params and output of 'puts group_params' from the logs. I just removed some additional params that aren't relevant to the question to keep it focused/readable

Comment: @JohanWentholt I need to use select_tag in this case because a custom name is required for the select element so I can't use f.select

Comment: @phauwn Why don't use `f.select` which fix the naming convention of it

Comment: I believe not. With the code you have, `"custom_people"=>"1"` should be outside of `"group"=>{}`

Comment: @ArupRakshit Its already inside! `"group"=>{"description"=>"something", "custom_people"=>"1", "commit"=>"Save"}` That is why i've asked him to check the params again.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I need the custom name, can't use f.select

Comment: @Pavan Hm true. I misread it.

Comment: @Pavan, you're right... I deleted the } when I cut and paste... will fix above. Sorry

Comment: @phauwn Why can't you use `f.select`? Isn't the `custom_people` a model attribute?

Comment: @Pavan no, it's not a model attribute... it would take a lot of non-relevant explanation as to why that needs to be a custom name.

Comment: @phauwn Did you try the answer I gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the `select_tag` manually to fix the problem. With the below code, you now get the custom_people inside the `groups: {..}` params.

```
<%= select_tag 'group[custom_people]', People.all  %>
```

Comment: getting error: unknown attribute 'custom_people' for Group, assuming that's because it's not a model attribute, as I mentioned above.

Comment: So it means now it is present in the `groups: {}` params. So what you want to do with it? Error comes as you are trying to save in the DB..

Comment: @phauwn `'group[custom_people]'` made it possible to put it inside the `"group"=>{"description"=>"something", "custom_people"=>"1",},`.. and you can check now what is inside the `group_params`... So what is the next thing you want to do? First problem is solved..

Comment: Yea, you're right... got it, I'm slow today ;). Thanks, will mark your answer correct.